# calling self test case does not increment the number of tests passed?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Suppose I have a unittest like this

```
class TestABC(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    ....

  def test001_abc(self):
    ....

  def test002_abc(self):
    ....

  def test003_bac(self):
    ....
    self.test001_abc()
```

But the output shows `Run 3 tests in 10.962s`. I believe that the last `self.test001_bac()` had been ran, but can we indicate this in the test count?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last "test" was run as part of test_003_bac, so unittest does not see it as a separate test.  I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this, but running one test inside another is not a good idea.  nose supports the concept of [Test Generators](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-generators), which might do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense. There are just three tests in your code; the fact that the last test calls another test doesn't magically "split" the test case into two, independent tests - `test003_bac` is still just one, single test.